# Meta-regression in metafor - subgroup differences

Tags: metafor

I have performed a meta-regression following the example found in [here](https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/plots:forest_plot_with_subgroups).
This is the code that I'm using adapted to my dataset:

> #### fit meta-regression model to test for subgroup differences
>
> resMeta <- rma(xi=nphy, ti=ni, mods = ~ pop, data=metaAAS)

'metaAAS' holds the data from a csv file, and 'pop' is the moderator.
The problem is that 'pop' has 4 levels, described as 0,1,2 and 3, and the output for the test of moderators (QM) is showing only one degree of freedom, instead of 3 (number of levels - 1):

**Test of Moderators (coefficient 2):
QM(df = 1) = 8.7150, p-val = 0.0032**

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
resMeta <- rma(measure="IR", xi=nphy, ti=ni, mods = ~ factor(pop), data=metaAAS)
```

or

```
resMeta <- rma(measure="IR", xi=nphy, ti=ni, mods = ~ 0 + factor(pop), data=metaAAS)
```

depending on how you want to parameterize the model. See https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:models_with_or_without_intercept for a discussion of the difference.

Comment: Thank you, @wolfgang. The 'factor' function was the missing part. I also had to add measure="IR" to specify the outcome.